# Excel formul to count Table Range using month from date text

Tags: excel, count, formula

I have an excel workbook where I am trying to count the number of apples in a named table. The workbook has multle sheets each named Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. with a corresponding table range of the same name.

My main worksheet has a list of months as columns and fruit as rows, I want to use a countif or suitable function to count the number of each fruit per month using the column heading as the worksheet portion of the formula.

This is what I have tried, this works, but has to be manually coded for each month, i would prefer it be more dynamic.

`=COUNTIF(JAN[Labels],$A2)` 
*Note: A2 contains the word apple*

I have tried to get the month from the column date but it doesnt work
`=COUNTIF(TEXT(E25,"mmm")[Labels],$A2)`

This is roughly what the "master" table should look like (for clarity)

```
|       | Jan-20 | Feb-20 | Mar-20 | .... |
| Apple |   4    |    3   |   5    | ...  |
| Pear  |   5    |    4   |   9    | ...  |
```

EDIT:
Just to assist with anyone trying to help, this is roughly what a table on another sheet will look like:

```
| invoice | labels|
| 12535   | Apple |
| 12536   | Pear  |
| 12537   | Apple |
```

This table would be a named table of Jan or Feb, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found an answer, combining the above answer by Variatus with an additional new row.

```
 |   A  |     B     |     C     |      D    |
1|      |   Jan-20  |   Feb-20  |   Mar-20  |
2|      |JAN[Labels]|FEB[Labels]|MAR[Labels]| <- =UPPER(TEXT(B1,"MMM"))&"[Labels]"
3|Apple |     5     |     7     |      3    | <- =COUNTIF(INDIRECT(B$2),$A3)
4|Pear  |     7     |     2     |      9    |
5|Orange|     1     |     3     |      3    |
```

So formula in B2 makes an uppercase text value of the month from B1 plus the column name Labels.
The formula in B3 (and down) counts the number of instances of the fruit from the named table & column shown in B2.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(TEXT(G2,"mmm")),"A")
```

G2 contains a proper date.

Here is a variation of the above where column 2 of the table is specified as the range to count in.

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(INDIRECT(TEXT(G2,"mmm")),0,2),"B")
```

If you must use column captions to identify the column I would suggest MATCH to find it.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with the named table column [Labels]  portion of the formula.